# JavaScript: Can I declare a variable by querying which function is called? (Newbie)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm working with an existing JavaScript-powered cart module that I am trying to modify. I do not know JS and for various reasons need to work with what is already in place.

The text that appears for my quantity box is defined within an existing function:

```
function writeitems() {

var i;
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var item=items[i];
    var placeholder=document.getElementById("itembuttons" + i);
    var s="<p>";

    // options, if any
    if (item.options) {
        s=s+"<select id='options"+i+"'>";
        var j;
        for (j=0; j<item.options.length; j++) {
            s=s+"<option value='"+item.options[j].name+"'>"+item.options[j].name+"</option>";
        }
        s=s+"</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }



// add to cart

    s=s+"Quantity: <input id='quantity"+i+"' value='1' size='3'/> ";

    s=s+"<input type='submit' value='Add to Cart' onclick='addtocart("+i+"); return false;'/></p>";
    }


    placeholder.innerHTML=s;
}
refreshcart(false);
}
```

I have two different types of quantity input boxes; one (donations) needs to be prefaced with a dollar sign, and one (items) should be blank.

I've taken the existing additem function, copied it, and renamed it so that there are two identical functions, one for items and one for donations.  The additem function is below:

```
function additem(name,cost,quantityincrement) {
if (!quantityincrement) quantityincrement=1; 
var index=items.length;
items[index]=new Object;
items[index].name=name;
items[index].cost=cost;
items[index].quantityincrement=quantityincrement;

document.write("<span id='itembuttons" + index + "'></span>");

return index;

}
```

Is there a way to declare a global variable based on which function (additem or adddonation) is called so that I can add that into the writeitems function so display or hide the dollar sign as needed? Or is there a better solution?

I can't use HTML in the body of the cart page because of the way it is currently coded, so I'm depending on the JS to take care of it.

Any help for a newbie is welcome. Thanks!

UPDATE 3/22:
Ok, I've edited the .js file as such:
        var items=new Array;
    var cart=new Array;
    var isDonation=false;

```
function additem(name,cost,quantityincrement) {
var isDonation=false;
if (!quantityincrement) quantityincrement=1; 
var index=items.length;
items[index]=new Object;
items[index].name=name;
items[index].cost=cost;
items[index].quantityincrement=quantityincrement;

document.write("<span id='itembuttons" + index + "'></span>");

return index;
}

function adddonation(name,cost,quantityincrement) {
var isDonation=true;
if (!quantityincrement) quantityincrement=1; 
var index=items.length;
items[index]=new Object;
items[index].name=name;
items[index].cost=cost;
items[index].quantityincrement=quantityincrement;

document.write("<span id='itembuttons" + index + "'></span>");

return index;
}

...

function writeitems() {

var i;
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var item=items[i];
    var placeholder=document.getElementById("itembuttons" + i);
    var s="";

    // options, if any
    if (item.options) {
        s=s+"<select id='options"+i+"'>";
        var j;
        for (j=0; j<item.options.length; j++) {
            s=s+"<option value='"+item.options[j].name+"'>"+item.options[j].name+"</option>";
        }
        s=s+"</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }



// add to cart
    if (!isDonation) {
    s=s+"<input id='quantity"+i+"' size='3' type='hidden'/>";
    s=s+"<input type='submit' value='Add to Cart' onclick='addtocart("+i+"); return false;'/><br /><br />";
    }
    else {

    s=s+"$<input id='quantity"+i+"' size='3'/>.00 ";
    s=s+"<input type='submit' value='Add to Cart' onclick='addtocart("+i+"); return false;'/><br /><br />";
    }

    placeholder.innerHTML=s;
}
refreshcart(false);
}
```

The resulting page isn't differentiating between the additem and adddonation functions is the output. Changing if/else statement to isDonation=true changes all output universally, and isDonation=false changes likewise, but also universally.

I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: You shouldn't ever have two _identical_ functions, but I assume you really mean _almost_ identical. That said, can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with both functions and some minimal html?

Comment: I truly know nothing about programming JavaScript. I can make simple, non-programming tweaks to existing code, but I'm afraid a fiddle is beyond me at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty ugly, but you could solve this by having a global variable isDonation. Set this at the beginning of your additem to false, and to true in adddonation. Then in the writeitems function you can check the value and use it to condition your output.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  Unfortunately, I truly don't know enough about JS to be able to implement your suggestion (although I understand it in the abstract). If I set a global variable, won't it override any value I give it within the additem and adddonation functions?

Comment: Also, can you supply an example of how to check the value and create the conditional statement?  I've played around a bit using basic JS tutorials I've found, but I'm doing it wrong since the output remains the same in each case.

Sorry to be a pest.